# What is the technical difference between .jsx and .js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to understand the technical difference between them so as to determine the appropriate one to use.

I've realised that they can both have same content and sometimes used interchangeably in some projects.

How does `.jsx` files differ from `.js`?

Comment: .jsx will be finally compiled to .js

Comment: Use js https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/52#issuecomment-72844613

Comment: As of 2017-08, [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) uses plain `.js` when you generate a new app, FWIW.

Comment: this is very good question. why opinion-based?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu, because both are working fine and it seems a question of personal preferences ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - .JS vs .JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update for Newer Users**

The JSX Compiler tool has been removed as JSXTransformer has been deprecated. The React Team recommends using another tool such as the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

---

If you wish to keep the [JSX source code](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) intact for better maintainability, I would keep them as `.jsx` files. Using the [JSX Compiler](http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html), either manually or via build script, will convert your JSX syntax to normal JavaScript files.

*Note:* It is possible to serve JSX files in your production environment but React will give you `console` notices about reduced performance.

---

Personally, I would use something like [gulp-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsx) or  [gulp-reactify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-reactify) to convert the files.

Example with **gulp-jsx**:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jsx  = require('gulp-jsx');

gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src('path/to/*.jsx')
    .pipe(jsx())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Take a look at Paul and Sebastian's rational behind .js favored extension over .jsx https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3582#issuecomment-89411479.

Comment: Airbnb say jsx: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming

Comment: I use `.jsx` for react components, following the convention of saving coffeescript files as `.coffee`. Yes, it will eventually compile to javascript, but using the appropriate file extension to describe what is actually inside the file is a better convention

Comment: Does this really answer the question of the difference between .max and .js files?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this discussion:
[ReactJS - .JS vs .JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx)
JSX is neither JS nor HTML, so giving it its extension helps indicate what it is. You can find some more discussions and docs linked there.