# Not able to find real difference between .jsx and js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> My .js file is:-

```
var React = require('react');
export default class AmortizationChart extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var items = this.props.data.map(function (year, index) {

            return (

                <tr key={index}>

                    <td>{index + 1}</td>

                    <td className="currency interest">{Math.round(year.interestY).toLocaleString()}</td>

                    <td className="currency">{Math.round(year.balance).toLocaleString()}</td>

                </tr>

                );

});
```

> Now same I can Write also in .jsx file.So what is the difference which
>   file I sould take .js or .jsx?

Comment: You can find a good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887678/react-js-what-extension-to-use-jsx-or-just-js

Comment: It's just convention.

Answer (score 3):

This bit *is* JSX:

```
<tr key={index}>
  <td>{index + 1}</td>
  <td className="currency interest">{Math.round(year.interestY).toLocaleString()}</td>
  <td className="currency">{Math.round(year.balance).toLocaleString()}</td>
</tr>
```

This only works because you're loading your .js file as `text/babel`. Try it with `text/javascript` and you'll get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

React's own documentation has a good article on JSX here: [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).