# ReactJS - .JS vs .JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, file-type

There is something I find very confusing when working in `React.js`.

There are plenty of examples available on internet which use `.js` files with `React` but many others use `.jsx` files.

I have read about `JSX` files and my understanding is that they just let you write `HTML` tags within your `JavaScript`.
But the same thing can be written in `JS` files as well.

So what is the actual difference between `.js` and `.jsx` ?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, but, if you're an adept to clean code you can follow the Airbnb Coding Style, which recommend using .jsx https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#basic-rules

Answer (score 447, accepted):

There is none when it comes to file extensions. Your bundler/transpiler/whatever takes care of resolving what type of file contents there is.

There are however some other considerations when deciding what to put into a `.js` or a `.jsx` file type. Since JSX isn't standard JavaScript one could argue that anything that is not "plain" JavaScript should go into its own extensions ie., `.jsx` for JSX and `.ts` for TypeScript for example.

There's a [good discussion here available for read](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/pull/985)

Comment: Nice link! For me [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904) is something also interesting!

Comment: Well said.  JSX is neither JS or HTML, so giving it its own extension helps indicate what it is--even if using `.jsx` isn't a requirement

Comment: The distinction between .js and .jsx files was useful before Babel, but it’s not that useful anymore.

Answer (score 106):

In most of the cases it’s only a need for the transpiler/bundler, which might not be configured to work with JSX files, but with JS! So you are forced to use JS files instead of JSX.

And since react is just a library for javascript, it makes no difference for you to choose between JSX or JS. **They’re completely interchangeable!**

In some cases users/developers might also choose JSX over JS, because of code highlighting, but the most of the newer editors are also viewing the react syntax correctly in JS files.

Answer (score 68):

JSX tags (`<Component/>`) are clearly not standard javascript and have no special meaning if you put them inside a naked `<script>` tag for example. Hence all React files that contain them are JSX and not JS.

By convention, the entry point of a React application is usually .js instead of .jsx even though it contains React components. It could as well be .jsx. Any other JSX files usually have the .jsx extension.

In any case, the reason there is ambiguity is because ultimately the extension does not matter much since the transpiler happily munches any kinds of files as long as they are actually JSX.

My advice would be: don't worry about it.

Comment: Even `var elem = <div>Text</div>;` is not a standard html element; it does not support `appendChild`, `classList` and probably other html features. If you want html  tags directly in javascript it is better to use the template literal (the backtick `\``) together with `innerHtml` or `outerHtml`.

Answer (score 52):

As other mentioned `JSX` is not a standard Javascript extension. It's better to name your entry point of Application based on `.js` and for the rest components, you can use `.jsx`.

I have an important reason for why I'm using `.JSX` for all component's file names. 
Actually, In a large scale project with huge bunch of code, if we set all React's component with `.jsx` extension, It'll be easier while navigating to different javascript files across the project(like helpers, middleware, etc.) and you know this is a React Component and not other types of the javascript file.

Comment: Also if your are using VS Code, .jsx files has a different file icon

Answer (score 31):

As already mentioned, there is no difference, if you create a file with `.jsx` or `.js`.

I would like to bring another expect of creating the files as `.jsx` while creating a component.

This is not mandatory, but an architectural approach that we can follow. So, in large projects we divide our components as Presentational components or Container components. Just to brief, in container components we write the logic to get data for the component and render the Presentational component with props. In presentational components, we usually donot write functional logic, presentational components are used to represent the UI with required props.

So, if you check the definition on JSX in [React documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

It says,

> ```
>  const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
> ```
>
> It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript.  We
> recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look
> like.  JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with
> the full power of JavaScript.
>
> JSX produces React “elements”. Instead of artificially separating
> technologies by putting markup and logic in separate files, React
> separates concerns with loosely coupled units  called “components”
> that contain both.
>
> React doesn’t require using JSX, but most people find it helpful as a
> visual aid when  working with UI inside the JavaScript code. It also
> allows React to show more useful  error and warning messages.

It means, It's not mandatory but you can think of creating presentational components with '.jsx' as it actually binds the props with the UI. and container components, as `.js` files as those contains logic to get the data.

It's a convention that you can follow while creating the `.jsx` or `.js` files, to logically and physically separate the code.

Answer (score 13):

Besides the mentioned fact that JSX tags are not standard javascript, the reason I use .jsx extension is because with it Emmet still works in the editor - you know, that useful plugin that expands html code, for example ul>li into

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's possible to use Emmet for .js files in Visual Studio Code by adding the following to your settings.json: `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" }`, but yes, I agree that JSX code should use the .jsx extension if possible.

Answer (score 10):

JSX isn't standard JavaScript, based to Airbnb style guide 'eslint' could consider this pattern

```
// filename: MyComponent.js
function MyComponent() {
  return <div />;
}
```

as a warning, if you named your file MyComponent.jsx it will pass , unless if you edit the eslint rule 
you can check the style guide [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-filename-extension.md)

Answer (score 4):

if you use `.jsx` it will be treated as a react page so its features will be applied by extensions automatically. for example if you use [emmet](https://emmet.io/) in `.jsx`  file, `.container`, this will create a div with `className` not `class`

```
    <div className="container"></div>
```

if you apply the same emmet inside a `js` file, you would get this:

```
    <div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

copied from: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

> **Why JSX?** React embraces the fact that rendering logic is inherently coupled with other UI logic: how events are handled, how
> the state changes over time, and how the data is prepared for display.
>
> Instead of artificially separating technologies by putting markup and
> logic in separate files, React separates concerns with loosely coupled
> units called “components” that contain both. We will come back to
> components in a further section, but if you’re not yet comfortable
> putting markup in JS, this talk might convince you otherwise.
>
> React doesn’t require using JSX, but most people find it helpful as a
> visual aid when working with UI inside the JavaScript code. It also
> allows React to show more useful error and warning messages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29813302)

Comment: this quote is about JSX in general and does not answer the question about .js and .jsx file extension

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the IDE or editor, `.jsx` has a different file icon :P. And it's a good practice to know what file it is without reading the code. The bundler and compiler might know it and will take care of everything, but telling the difference between `.jsx` and `.js` from just the file name will help you as a developer a lot.

EDIT: jsx is more than js, it is javascript + xml, which allows you to write html inside a js file without using template strings. For this reason it's a good practice to use `.jsx`for your react files, instead of `.js` (which is also valid).

Answer (score 3):

**CLEAR your doubt for diffrence between .js & .jsx**

In a ReactJS application, both .js and .jsx file extensions are commonly used. Here's the difference between them:

**1. .js Files:**

- JavaScript files with a `.js` extension are standard JavaScript files.
- They can contain regular JavaScript code and are not specific to React.
- You can write JavaScript logic, define functions, variables, classes, etc.
- However, when using React, `.js` files are typically used for non-component-related code, such as utility functions, helper functions, or configuration files.

**2. .jsx Files:**

- `.jsx` files are JavaScript files that contain `JSX` syntax.
- JSX (JavaScript XML) is an extension to JavaScript that allows you to write HTML-like code within JavaScript.
- JSX is a syntax extension provided by React and is used to define React components.
- React components are the building blocks of a React application, and they encapsulate reusable pieces of UI.
- JSX files contain both JavaScript logic and HTML-like markup (`JSX` syntax) that define the structure and appearance of React components.

> In summary, `.js` files are standard JavaScript files used for general
> JavaScript code, while `.jsx` files are JavaScript files that contain
> JSX syntax and are specifically used for defining React components.

**For your QUESTION:**

Yes, you can use both `.js` and `.jsx` files in your React application. React supports both file extensions, allowing you to mix regular JavaScript code and JSX syntax within your project.

Typically, **you would use `.jsx` files for defining React components** that contain JSX syntax. This allows you to write **HTML-like markup directly in your JavaScript code**, making it easier to describe the structure and appearance of your components.

On the other hand, **.js files can be used for regular JavaScript code that is not specific to React components.** This includes utility functions, helper functions, configuration files, or any other JavaScript **logic that doesn't involve JSX.**

*When importing components or files into other parts of your React application, you would specify the file extension (`.js` or `.jsx`) depending on the type of file you are importing.*

**For Example:**

```js
// Importing a component from a .jsx file
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.jsx';

// Importing a regular JavaScript file
import utilityFunction from './utilityFunction.js';
```

> Remember to configure your build system (such as Babel or webpack) to
> handle both `.js` and `.jsx` file extensions and transpile JSX code into regular JavaScript code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use always `js` instead of `jsx`.

This is the [suggested guideline](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904) of React.js Team.

I don't think there's any benefits to use `jsx` in nowdays.

Comment: "I don't think there's any benefits to use `jsx` in nowdays." That's true when it comes to build-time stuff like bundling, but using the `jsx` extension in particular IDEs mean that they support HTML markup without needing (much) additional setup or having to specifically denote that a `js` or `ts` file should use JSX syntax. It's essentially personal preference these days, it seems.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut I agree with you.