# Reactjs correction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know if this is allowed in React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo, { ReactComponent } from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    let helloWorld = 'Welcome to good programming React';
     return ( 
      <div className="App">
         <h2> {helloWorld}</h2>
          </div>
           ); 
          }
}

//another way to write this same code as above
class Car extends React.component {
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>we can going to see various cars </h1>
    );
  }
}
let app = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDom.render(<Layout/>, app)
```

These two classes are in the same namespace. Can I have two classes in the same namespace? How can I use export default, or will i have two export default lines?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can write multiple class in same component.

index.js

```
export const App = () =>{}
export const App2 = () =>{}
```

and import in other component like this.

```
import {App, App2} from './index'
```

like this you need to write **Car** and **App** component in Layout component then import here.

Answer (score 1):

Export default allows you to directly export a single reference. If you have multiple references you want to export, use the standard export syntax, like this:

```
export { App, Car }
```

Then is can be imported in other files like this:

```
import { App, Car } from './PATH_TO_FILE.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two classes in the same module (modules are the namespace equivalent in JavaScript - a module creates a script-global [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), preventing namespace collisions between internal members of other modules, but not with namespace collisions arising from exported module members).

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

`export default` allows you to export only one object as the default exported module member.

If your Car class was implemented in a separate file, this is how you would export it as the default export (assuming it was named `Car.js` or `Car.jsx`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Car extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>we can going to see various cars </h1>
    )
  }
}
```

To use it from another file:

```
import Car from './Car'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx) explains why .js or .jsx for the choice of the file name extension.