# When should I use .jsx and .js particularly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-start

I have a React project in which *everything was running fine* until I changed the extension of ***App.js*** from the **components** folder to ***App.jsx***

Here is a screenshot of the folder:
[image: React folder structure]

When I run `npm start`, got the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\phone\src\components\App.js'
```

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./components/App"
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**package.json**

```
      ...
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      ...
```

I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169636/12611597 that these extensions are completely interchageable. How to configure the transpiler?

So Why is this error ocurring?

Comment: Can you add the `start` part of your package json. Is this a Create-React-App?

Comment: yes, this create-react-app

Comment: post your index.js

Comment: What does the import in `index.js` look like?

Comment: I think `index.js` import is meant defaulting to .js extension for `App.js`. So while importing only for `App.js` file specify the extension `.jsx`.

Comment: It is for the global module that goes with the `root` div tag

Answer (score 0):

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\phone\src\components*App.js*'

Remove the .js part and it should work. It's a bit individual, but as a good practice, you can write .jsx if you are using jsx file, and .js if it is a javascript module. Some code editors force you to write jsx( for example webstorm), if you use typescript, then you already have to specify .tsx and .ts extensions. Speaking easier, use .jsx if you return jsx from your component, write .js if it is a javascript file. And during the imports don't specify the extension.

Comment: While you are not wrong per se, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: When I answered,, the question was not updated with more details)