# Are these Microsoft docs wrong for having JSX in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In the following [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) (as well as many others), they'll have a file explicitly called `App.js` but then have code like:

```
    return (
    <>
        <h5 className="card-title">Welcome {name}</h5>
        {accessToken ? 
            <p>Access Token Acquired!</p>
            :
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={RequestAccessToken}>Request Access Token</Button>
        }
    </>
);
```

Isn't this `JSX`? I've noticed this being done a lot and it's starting to confuse me as to how JS and JSX differ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - .JS vs .JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx)

Comment: @MattU Thanks, but I read that before and no, it doesn't answer my question. Top answer there states that "anything that is not "plain" JavaScript should go into its own extensions". Well `<h5` is definitely not plain JS and yet according to Microsoft it should go in a JS file.

Comment: It says "one could argue" that point, the answer doesn't state that as fact. The key in that answer is actually "Your bundler/transpiler/whatever takes care of resolving what type of file contents there is."

Comment: Are you asking how JS and JSX differ as concepts, or just the filename extensions? Extensions are just conveniences.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion about `JSX vs JS` in the AirBNB repo here: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/pull/985

Essentially, in bigger React projects especially, differentiating a .jsx file versus a .js file can come down to identifying what is used as a React component versus what is perhaps just plain Javascript logic. When it comes down to reading a .jsx and .js file, you don't need to worry about whether the extension is .jsx or .js - it will run fine as it does.

So yes technically the extension should be `.jsx`, but ultimately it does not matter.