# Difference between javascript and javascriptreact in vscode supported languages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The `vscode` documentation does not appear to specify the differences between `javascript` and `javascriptreact`.

Both appear to work the same including the closing tag per documentation example.

If one is using a `reactjs` project with `.js` file extension - what is the the correct setting? And again, where can the differences be tracked

**Edit**:
Changed the verb "recommend" to "correct setting."

Comment: There is none. Their [official example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial) is using `.js` for React projects. [It doesn't matter at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169521/11613622) Just a matter of preference and if someone wants to write/use an extension or configure settings separately for `js` and `jsx`. The same applies for `ts` and `tsx`. Try searching `ext:jsx` and `ext:js` on marketplace. You will rarely find an extension that is available for one but not for another.

Comment: I think this question is ok and should be reopened. It is about a programming tool. It is pretty narrow in scope and seems answerable. The snark about the question being closed isn't needed though.