# Difference between Js and Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Got a doubt while I am working on react js. In the below code, I have used both js and jsx. Both responds in the same way. Then why should we use jsx specifically.

When I searched online, I am only able to get the difference between js and jsx but I  also need to know whether jsx is built specifically for react js or we can run jsx outside the react js project.

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './Components/Layout'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello, This is home page
        </div>
    )
}
```

About.js

```
export default function About() {
    return (
        <div>Hello, This is about page</div>
    )
}
```

Layout.jsx

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <div>
            Home | About
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Writing `<div className="App">` is not possible in "normal" js. Instead you'd have to write `React.createElement('div', props, ...etc)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - .JS vs .JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx)

Comment: No... It is not the same actually. There only the difference between Js and Jsx alone has been explained. I also need to know whether we can use jsx outside my react project.

Comment: As long as the build processor supports it. https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/#jsx parcel supports it without react.

Comment: Parcel supports JSX automatically when it detects you are using React. is from [link](https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/#jsx). It also need to detect react it seems.

Comment: No, https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#jsx preact is supported too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) is a programming language.

[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is an extension to that programming language which lets you specify the shape of a DOM using XML-like syntax. JSX needs converting to JS before browsers can deal with it.

The choice of *file extension* you use depends on the tools which you use which might pay attention to the file extension.

Such tools include Webpack, Babel, ESLint, and Prettier.

> In the below code, I have used both js and jsx. Both responds in the same way.

Your tools appear to be configured so they do not distinguish between `.js` and `.jsx` files and treat both as JSX.

> Then why should we use jsx specifically.

It can be useful to distinguish between the two, especially if a file might be used in a different context (without the toolchain needed to convert JSX to JS).

> And I need to know whether jsx is built specifically for react js or shall we create a just a file and write jsx code.

JSX was *designed* for use with React.

That doesn't mean you can't use it without React (see [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-jsx-without-react-21d23346e5dc), and [here](https://blog.r0b.io/post/using-jsx-without-react/), and [here](https://adostes.medium.com/you-dont-need-react-to-use-jsx-b78dd2a95c27) for some results gleaned by typing *JSX without React* into Google).

You can't *just* write JSX, as I mentioned, you need a toolchain to convert it into JS before a browser (or Node.js or whatever you are running your JS on) can do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

According to React Docs, you can write react code in a `.js` file as well as
`.jsx` file

In `.jsx` You are telling your code editor, Hey bro I am writing react code. So it would give you autocompletes and IntelliSense accordingly.

One way to test is to use `emmet` in both files you won't able to use it in the `.js` file until and unless you manually change the language type