# VS code update 1.78.2 javascript white text

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Hey just updated my vscode and now vscode doesnt necessarily highlight my code as it used to, ie classes in green, functions in yellow etc. Any ideas?

[image: example of vscode window not highlighting javascript properly]

Tried playing around with some settings the language mode in the bottom right to no avail.

Comment: That appears to be React rather than vanilla JavaScript. Do you have a React extension? Is the file recognised as such?

Comment: Do you have node packages installed?

Comment: Shouldn't that file have a `.jsx` suffix?

Comment: tried with a ```.jsx``` suffix as well no help, i do have a react extension and yes the node packages are installed

Comment: Status bar says "JavaScript". I'd expect "JavaScript JSX". I'm not sure how it worked before the update (I don't know if React enforces file extensions).

Comment: solution was the update enabled a new default theme which at night hours doesnt show "high contrast" really annoying sry everyone thanks for support

Comment: This is a tool question and doesn't relate to coding. check the release notes at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78 and/ or try the newer 1.79?

Comment: @spender I don't really think that matters for react.js code. As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to the stackoverflow community,

One reason could be that your theme is incorrect, specifically, your theme is set on the `visual studio` one(which does not have syntax highlight). However, you can just set it simply to the `Dark+` theme to start using syntax highlighting.

Hope this helped you!

###### Helpful links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2dXlvPw3qQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba_aEnrbnBU