# In react project, what is the difference between react file naming file.js and file.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

In both files, I use

```
import React from 'react'
```

and I work with the same workspace and the same syntax, I didn't find any problems to deal with.

I think this difference has something to do with the specific files (vanilla JS and React) or Giving these things a little more formality

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46169472/3001761?

Comment: From w3 schools:


JSX stands for JavaScript XML.
JSX allows us to write HTML elements in JavaScript and place them in the DOM without any createElement()  and/or appendChild() methods.

JSX converts HTML tags into react elements.

Comment: Someone asked this question before. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169472/reactjs-js-vs-jsx) thread.

Answer (score 1):

In a React project, the main difference between JSX and JS files lies in how they define and structure components.

JSX files contain a mixture of JavaScript code and XML-like syntax to define the structure and appearance of React components. On the other hand, JS files typically hold JavaScript code that can include logic, functions, and imports.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between **".js"** and **".jsx"** in a React project is mainly a matter of convention. Both can contain JavaScript and JSX code. Using **.jsx** makes it clearer that the file contains JSX code, and may help with syntax highlighting and code formatting in some editors. However, using **.js** is simpler and more common, and does not require any special configuration.

In my organisation, the ES-Lint is configured in such a way that it throws errors if we use **.js** instead of **.jsx** for components.

It ultimately comes down to your team's preference and conventions followed.