# JSX works in plain JavaScript file, how?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsx, next.js

I have the latest version of VsCode, and I am following a tutorial to create a basic next.js app

I noticed that the tutorial uses JSX in .JS files, and my editor does not complain about the JSX.

How is this possible? Does VsCode by default recognize JSX in .JS files? And does next.js automatically compile JSX?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887678/react-js-what-extension-to-use-jsx-or-just-js

Answer (score 2):

Yes VS Code support JSX in both `*.js` and `*.jsx` files out of the box. This only impacts intellisense and other editor features. We do not provide any built-in compiler integration but you can easily set up your own [with tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) or using the command line

Behind the scenes, the reason jsx is enabled in `*.js` files that we create an implicit [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) that looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```