# Using .js file extensions whilst writing scripts that return jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx, file-extension

I started using react as my ui framework of choice. Upon my adventure through the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/) I noticed that when using the `create-react-app` script to spin up a new react boilerplate, they used `.js` file extension on scripts that where returning `jsx` code. When I asked my colleague, he told me that you should use the `.jsx` extension on scripts that are returning this kind of code.

I'm a bit lost here as if both works, wouldn't it just be better to go with the `.js` extension as at the end of the day it's javascript that we are writing.

My question, what is considered best practise. (*I kinda have a feeling it would be to use the `.jsx` extensions on these types of scripts, but I'd love to hear the community's view on this*).

Comment: I'm not super knowledgeable on this, but I have made multiple react apps with `create-react-app` and have always just used the `.js` extension. Never had a problem using jsx in those files as long as `react` is in scope.

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887678/react-js-what-extension-to-use-jsx-or-just-js) answer will help you

Comment: @MikhailKatrin your answer was good as well thanks for the link. For anyone hitting this page, this link is a must see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course both will work, but I suggest differentiating .js files from .jsx files and using .jsx for react/etc.
Why? First of all, jsx will error in a standard javascript execution environment of the browser, because standard javascript doesn't understand the various html/xml pieces.
Because we are transpiling the code, you can have it run, but .jsx is [not actually intended to be incorporated into ecmascript or browser javascript](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/).

- jsx within a standard js browser execution environment will error
- the .jsx file extension is pretty well established, might as well utilize the extra specificity
- When you have a web app, it can sometimes be useful to be running non-react, non-jsx scripts.  If you use .js for react and jsx executing files, then the .js extension is no longer allocatable to clearly call out browser-javascript-compatible files.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The pattern I decided to go with was, if the file returns `jsx` then that's what the extension would be and from there I'd usually use a `.js` extension and `barrell import` my `jsx` assets from inside the `index.js` which would be placed in directory containing the `jsx` file component.

Answer (score 7):

It's really up to personal preference.

My personal opinion is JavaScript is JavaScript, and I just use `.js`. Others will prefer to use `.jsx` in files that are JSX and `.js` in for things like utilities, in order to differentiate. The only important thing is to be consistent in whatever you choose (at least within one project).

In general, it doesn't matter.

The only time it might actually matter is based on your build pipeline. Some build pipelines may be configured to compile `.js` and `.jsx` with slightly different rules, but that would be based on your application (things like `create-react-app` don't care).

At the end of the day, you could use a `.cookiemonster` extension and it'd work just fine (as long as your build pipeline is configured to handle it).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't matter, is up to you to decide I prefer to use `.jsx` when I return the mix between HTML and JS and use `.js` only when I'm using plain JS or ES6.

I recommend you to read about this on [this issue on github](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/87).